# three.js convert_obj_three.py normals are missing

Tags: three.js

When converting from .obj file to .js file for use with three.js, the script convert_obj_three.py doesn't export normals.

How can I get the normals?

Comment: What tool is your model created with? I have no problems using Maya, although I do have to tick normals when exporting!

Comment: I'm using blender, the problem has been solved, by using geometry.computeVertexNormals();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting the model, blender has an option to include normals, check the box will do.
OR
using three.js

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals()
```

to compute the normal.